# gae-boilerplate documentation

Tags: google-app-engine, boilerplate

In my search for a good social login package for App Engine, I am giving gae-boilerplate a try. But I find there is no documentation except the readme file, which I think it is not enough at all.

I have many questions, among them:

- Should the boilerplate be used as a library or download and modify as needed?
- How should the boilerplate be updated?
- What does each model do?
- Where should my templates go?
- Should I have a different routes file?
- Should I derive my Handlers from BaseHandler?
- In general, what things should I implement in my pages? For example, I found out that I have to include a csrf_token in all POST requests. It would have been nice to know this in advance, and the many other things that I'm having to find out along the way, and which I implement without being sure if I'm supposed to be doing that.
- And some more...

My biggest problem is that Social login is not working, and I feel this boilerplate is a big monster with which I don't know where to start. To make things worse, it is hard to debug social auth from any machine that is not the production one. Thats why I'm desperately looking for some docs.

I have not found anything in SO, and I guess there must be more people in my situation. So, any pointers to documentation that could help to understand gae-boilerplate a little bit better would be very appreciated.

EDIT: I switched to gae-boilerplate in a site that I had previously working. Maybe most of my problems come from the way that I have tried to integrate gae-boilerplate and my existing site. As a result I have tried to treat gae-boilerplate as a library, and keep my own templates, handlers, static files and such.

Thank you guys!

EDIT 2: After trying other options, I have to say that I am very happy with gae-simpleauth. It works really well, and Alex's support is superb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to answer most of your questions below:

- Should the boilerplate be used as a library or download and modify as needed?

  - You can modify it as needed based on your specific requirements.
- How should the boilerplate be updated?

  - What do you mean?
- What does each model do?

  - `User` and `SocialUser` are pretty self explanatory. `LogVisit` and `LogEmail` are used for auditing purposes.
- Where should my templates go?

  - In the templates directory
- Should I have a different routes file?

  - No, you can use the existing file for all your routes.
- Should I derive my Handlers from `BaseHandler`?

  - It't not mandatory but I would recommend to do so. `BaseHandler` is very handy and provides a lot of good stuff.
- In general, what things should I implement in my pages?

  - What exactly do you mean?

In general, you can use gae-boilerplate as a reference on top of which you will built your own project. Study the code step by step, try to figure out what is the purpose of each file and library used and how they work together. This way you will gain good knowledge of a lot of things like jinja templating, oauth2, etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for answering some of my questions. About "How should the boilerplate be updated?", boilerplate is being modified every day, if you use it like a library, you just update it. But if you use it as a reference, how can you update to the latest version if you have already modified it? Also, I guess that there really are no other docs, right? Your last paragraph throws much light on how gae-boilerplate is supposed to be used. It definitely has some great bits of code from which I'm learning. I am adapting an existing site to gae-boilerplate, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Regarding the update procedure, you need to monitor the changes in every new version and patch your own implementation with them, if you need them of course.

Comment: It doesn't stop to surprise me. Today, I got facebook login to work, and when I logged in, the first message that I get back on my site is **"The Facebook account isn't associated with any local account. If you already have a Google App Engine Boilerplate Account, you have sign in here or Create an account"**. What's the point of using social login if the first thing you do to your user after logging in with a social provider is telling him to fill a registration form on your site?

Comment: @ThanosMakris Can you please answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31986909/what-is-the-use-of-bp-admin-folder-in-the-below-mentioned-boilerplate

Comment: @WasimThabraze Sure. I posted my answer. Hope it helps.