# What is the use of 'bp_admin' folder in the below mentioned Boilerplate?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate

I'm a beginner in  Google App engine (Python). I was looking for a boiler plate for my application and found this https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate .

Though this repository has a README, I don't understand it. I would like to know the use of 'bp_admin' folder. It would be really helpful if someone explains the use of each folder of the repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the *bp_admin* folder resides the code that provides functionality for the 'admin' user of the application. If you start the local development server and open http://localhost:8080/admin/, you are able to see geolocation of the users accessing the system and also manage:

- Users
- Email logs
- Visit logs

In *bp_includes*, there is code that provides the basic functionality upon which you will build your own content.

Folder *bp_content* is where you will put your code in order to extend the functionality of the basic boilerplate application.